# scp causing "'C:\ Program' is not recognized as an internal..."

Tags: linux, command-line, scp

I am trying to `scp` a file from a local machine to a remote one using the following command:

```
scp "local/file/path/file.txt" user@remote.server:"remote/file/path"
```

After entering the remote user's password, the following error message is presented:

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. lost connection`

There is nothing obvious that should be causing this error.  No file paths contain "C:\Program ". [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50630804/scp-from-linux-to-windows-c-program-is-not-recognized-error) was unhelpful. I am able to ssh into the remote machine successfully.

I would like to avoid using Filezilla, WinSCP or similar programs; this command needs to go into a script.

What could be causing this error?

EDIT:

The command is

```
scp "home/c/users/administrator/desktop/test.txt" administrator@defaultserver:"home/c/users/administrator/desktop"
```

EDIT2:

It seems like the error is being thrown before any file paths are considered. Running the debugger produces the following message before the error:

```
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /tmp
```

I downloaded OpenSSH as my SSH server. I extracted it to ~/Program Files/, which seems to be the only instance where that directory is relevant. Perhaps changing where the SSH server is installed to will change this error.

Comment: Anytime you need to specify a path that has a space in one or more folder names (i.e. "\Program Files" you need to enclose the entire file specification in quotes, i.e. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Blah Blah\program.exe"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could present the *actual* command line you used.

Comment: I updated my post with the true command.

Comment: Is there any reason you’re not using absolute paths? It appears you were intending to do so. If possible, try running both SSH client and server with `-vvv` to see more of what’s going on. Perhaps you can spot where the “Program Files” path comes into play.

Comment: I did some more searching and it seems that the error occurs before any filepath is passed, check out the new edit.

Comment: Installing an application under Linux to a path with a space in its name is asking for trouble. While *you* can escape spaces or put the path in quotes to preserve the space, there is no reason to assume the program has been set to do so.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that scp is built-in, I’ll have to check that later.

Comment: Do I understand right that your server is Linux? Yet you downloaded OpenSSH server? (why? OpenSSH is built-in on all major Linux distributions) And you put it to `Program Files` folder of your user home directory? Again why? This all makes hardly any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
scp /Users/PrashastKumar/Desktop/sample2.pdf prashasht@backup-new.xxx.com:/tmp
```

without giving inverted commas. This is working for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do the trick. On further inspection, the filepath doesn't seem to be considered before the command fails, see above at Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue today, trying to copy files to a Windows server running [OpenSSH-Win64](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v8.1.0.0p1-Beta). I solved the problem by adding `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH`, which is the recommended installation location, to the Windows path:

1. Open the *Control Panel*, go to the *System and Security* section and open up *System*.
2. Click on *Advanced System Settings* and, in the System Properties dialog box, click *Environmental Variables*.
3. In the *System Variables* section of the dialog box, select *Path* and click *Edit...*.
4. Click *New*, add the OpenSSH folder path and click *OK* to apply the change.

Then, do not forget to restart the OpenSSH service, either in the service management console or by running `net stop sshd`, followed by `net start sshd` in an elevated console.